# Двойная авторизация на soap сервере

Tags: php, soap, auth, аутентификация

Не получается авторизоваться на сервере soap, я новичок в этом. В документации к апи написано, что там двойная авторизация. Первая - авторизация сервера, вторая - авторизация внутри приложения. Пытаюсь авторизовать вот так(данные авторизации тестовые)

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://cdekff.ddns.net:40100/service.asmx?WSDL", array('trace' => 1)); 

$header = new SoapHeader("http://cdekff.ddns.net:40100/service.asmx", "Authentication", "Basic " . base64_encode("GTNO1:AAbb77dd") , false);
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));

$client->__soapCall("DeliveryTypes_GetList", array("Onwer54378", date("Y-m-d")."|C7E8E9C0-E0DB-47BA-BB37-363CF9AA1BCF"));  

var_dump($client->__getLastRequestHeaders());
```

Получаю вот это

```
stdClass Object ( [DeliveryTypes_GetListResult] => NO AUTHORIZATION [DeliveryTypesList] => stdClass Object ( ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Если соединение с самим сервером установлено, т.е. в самом $client видно то что соединение установлено (Можешь посмотреть содержимое $client и понять), то уже ошибка в вызове функции. Ты возможно передаешь либо не те данные какие ожидает функция, либо еще что то, посмотри корректны ли параметры с которыми ты пытаешься вызвать функцию "DeliveryTypes_GetList".